# Map User Id with Connection Id

Tags: wpf, signalr

I am creating a chat application using Wpf. So far I have created all the basic interfaces and most of the methods required. I am maintaining a database and it also saves details of all the users along with an auto incremental user id.

I am trying to use SignalR to send messages between online users connected to a hub. At the same time, a copy of the message is saved in the database with a sending user id and receiving user id.

When a message is sent to a user via a hub, I specify the user id of the receiver of the message. But when sending it to the receiver from the hub, I don't know how to map the user id with the connection id of the receiver.

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link

[Mapping ASP.NET SignalR Connections to Real Application Users](http://Mapping%20ASP.NET%20SignalR%20Connections%20to%20Real%20Application%20Users)

basically this is done by overriding `OnConnected` and `OnDisconnected` of `Hub` class

Comment: Thank you Arvin. I was able to send the User ID in the header when creating the connection.